# Changing x-labels and width while using catplot in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a sample dataset as follows;

```
pd.DataFrame({'Day_Duration':['Evening','Evening','Evening','Evening','Evening','Morning','Morning','Morning',
                         'Morning','Morning','Night','Night','Night','Night','Night','Noon','Noon','Noon',
                         'Noon','Noon'],'place_category':['Other','Italian','Japanese','Chinese','Burger',
                        'Other','Juice Bar','Donut','Bakery','American','Other','Italian','Japanese','Burger',\
                        'American','Other','Italian','Burger','American','Salad'],'Percent_delivery':[14.03,10.61,9.25,8.19,6.89,19.58,10.18,9.14,8.36,6.53,13.60,8.42,\
                                           8.22,7.66,6.67,17.71,10.62,8.44,8.33,7.50]})
```

The goal is to draw faceted barplot with `Day_duration` serving as facets, hence 4 facets in total. I used the following code to achieve the same,

```
import seaborn as sns
#g = sns.FacetGrid(top5_places, col="Day_Duration")
g=sns.catplot(x="place_category", y="Percent_delivery", hue='place_category',col='Day_Duration',\
                 data=top5_places,ci=None,kind='bar',height=4, aspect=.7)
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

Attached is the figure I got;

[image]

Can I kindly get help with 2 things, first is it possible to get only 5 values on the x-axis for each facet(rather than seeing all the values for each facet), second, is there a way to make the bars a bit wider. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Because you're using `hue` the api applies a unique color to each value of `place_category`, but it also expects each category to be in the plot, as shown in your image.

  - The final figure is a FacetGrid. Using `subplot` is the manual way of creating one.
- In order to plot only the top `n` categories for each `Day_Duration`, each plot will need to be done individually, with a custom color map.
- `cmap` is a dictionary with place categories as keys and colors as values. It's used so there will be one legend and each category will be colored the same for each plot.

  - Because we're not using the legend automatically generated by the plot, one needs to be created manually.
- `patches` uses `Patch` to create each item in the legend. (e.g. the rectangle, associated with color and name).

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch


# create a color map for unique values or place
place_cat = df.place_category.unique()
colors = sns.color_palette('husl', n_colors=10)
cmap = dict(zip(place_cat, colors))

# plot a subplot for each Day_Duration
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
for i, tod in enumerate(df.Day_Duration.unique(), 1):
    data = df[df.Day_Duration == tod].sort_values(['Percent_delivery'], ascending=False)
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i)
    p = sns.barplot(x='place_category', y='Percent_delivery', data=data, hue='place_category', palette=cmap)
    p.legend_.remove()
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.title(f'Day Duration: {tod}')

plt.tight_layout()
patches = [Patch(color=v, label=k) for k, v in cmap.items()]
plt.legend(handles=patches, bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc='center left', borderaxespad=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]